# addTrack after etablished connection

Tags: webrtc

I need to add my track and send to other peers after having etablished the connection I've followed the [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Perfect_negotiation#Implementing_perfect_negotiation)

```
pc.onnegotiationneeded = async () => {
  try {
    makingOffer = true;
    await pc.setLocalDescription();
    signaler.send({ description: pc.localDescription });
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    makingOffer = false;
  }
};
```

**onnegotiationneeded** is fired when we call **pc.addTrack** so I will remake the process offer -> answer -> ICE.

So I have a function which call getUserMedia and set the local video I've added a callback to apply addTrack to my peers

```
const handleActiveVideo = async (cb) => {
  const devices = await getVideoDevices();
  const localStream = await createLocalStream(devices[0].deviceId);
  setLocalVideoEl(localStream, devices[0].deviceId);

  cb((pc) => {
    localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
      pc.connection.addTrack(track, localStream);
    });
  });
};
```

But if I do that with an etablished connection when I add my local stream to the track with one peer it's ok all work fine but with my second peer I have this error on Firefox

> Remote description indicates ICE restart but offer did not request ICE
> restart (new remote description changes either the ice-ufrag or
> ice-pwd)

with Chrome

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on
> 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote answer sdp: Failed to apply
> the description for m= section with mid='0': Failed to set SSL role
> for the transport.

To recapitulate

1. connect my 2 peers without any tracks on both sides
2. start the video with my Peer1 ok I can see the video with my Peer2
3. start the video with my Peer2 error on Peer2 in the answer

> setRemoteDescription(description);